# Bounce Button Flutter

Tags: android, ios, animation, flutter

How to create an animation onbutton pressed. For example a bouncing animation like in the reflectly app.

What I did so far:

```
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2000),
    );

    _animation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.bounceInOut);

    super.initState();
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use this widget class for the same also if you want to make it disable animation then make it onPress null and pass child.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Bouncing extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback onPress;

  Bouncing({@required this.child, Key key, this.onPress})
      : assert(child != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _BouncingState createState() => _BouncingState();
}

class _BouncingState extends State<Bouncing>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double _scale;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      lowerBound: 0.0,
      upperBound: 0.1,
    );
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _scale = 1 - _controller.value;
    return Listener(
      onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent event) {
        if (widget.onPress != null) {
          _controller.forward();
        }
      },
      onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent event) {
        if (widget.onPress != null) {
          _controller.reverse();
          widget.onPress();
        }
      },
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: _scale,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
Bouncing(
  onPress: (){},
  child: Container()
);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Thank you for sharing an elegant solution. It's a pretty cool effect that when you hold the button down , it stays in the pressed position. I added the following delay to give time to see the animation when button-click is for screen transition: `onPress: () { Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 80), () => _someHandler()); }`, where bounce duration is set to: `duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),`

Answer (score 3):

Actually calling

```
_controller.addListener(() {
  setState(() {});
});
```

could cause some serious performance issues and lead to laggy animations. More info on that here:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-laggy-animations-how-not-to-setstate-f2dd9873b8fc

so I'd recommend doing this instead :

```
class BouncingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback onPress;

  BouncingWidget({@required this.child, Key key, this.onPress})
      : assert(child != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _BouncingWidgetState createState() => _BouncingWidgetState();
}

class _BouncingWidgetState extends State<BouncingWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> _scale;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 50),
    );
    _scale = Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.9)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.ease));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();   
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent event) {
        _controller.forward();
      },
      onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent event) {
        _controller.reverse();
        if (widget.onPress == null) return;
        widget.onPress();
      },
      child: ScaleTransition(
        scale: _scale,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
class AnimatedButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedButtonState createState() => _AnimatedButtonState();
}

class _AnimatedButtonState extends State<AnimatedButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      lowerBound: 0.0,
      upperBound: 0.1,
    );
    _animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double scale = 1 - _animationController.value;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapUp: _onTapUp,
      onTapDown: _onTapDown,
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: scale,
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 75,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(38.0),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black26,
                offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0),
                blurRadius: 5.0,
                spreadRadius: 0.25,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  void _onTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
    _animationController.reverse();
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with a floatingactionbutton and the special elevation effect?

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions here uses GestureDetector with onTapUp and onTapDown. However, onTapDown has some slight delay when user taps the screen, and requires them to hold the button to actually be tapped. To solve this, use the Listener widget with onPointerDown and onPointerUp instead.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BouncingButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BouncingButtonState createState() => _BouncingButtonState();
}

class _BouncingButtonState extends State<BouncingButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double _scale;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      lowerBound: 0.0,
      upperBound: 0.1,
    );
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _scale = 1 - _controller.value;
    return Listener(
      onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent event) {
        _controller.forward();
      },
      onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent event) {
        _controller.reverse();
      },
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: _scale,
        child: Container(
          height: 180,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: const Text("hello"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! The delay was really annoying, but this solves the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one too. It might help :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double _scale;
  AnimationController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(
        milliseconds: 200,
      ),
      lowerBound: 0.0,
      upperBound: 0.1,
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _scale = 1 - _controller.value;
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Tap on the Below Button',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400],fontSize: 20.0),),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
             Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTapDown: _onTapDown,
              onTapUp: _onTapUp,
              onLongPressMoveUpdate: _onMove,
              child: Transform.scale(
                scale: _scale,
                child: _animatedButtonUI,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ],

        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get _animatedButtonUI => Container(
        height: 70,
        width: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Color(0x80000000),
                blurRadius: 30.0,
                offset: Offset(0.0, 5.0),
              ),
            ],
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: [
                Color(0xFF0000FF),
                Color(0xFFFF3500),
              ],
            )),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'tap',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      );

  void _onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    _controller.forward();
  }

  void _onTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
    _controller.reverse();
  }

  void _onMove(LongPressMoveUpdateDetails details){
    _controller.reverse();

  }
    }
```